# 2sum performance improvement

Tags: python, performance, data-structures

The file contains 1 million integers, both positive and negative (there might be some repetitions!).This is your array of integers, with the ith row of the file specifying the ith entry of the array.

The task is to compute the number of target values t in the interval [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=t.

Numeric answer is an integer between 0 and 20001.

```
#ans = 427
data, count, n = set(map(int, open('2sum.txt').read().splitlines())), 0, 1000003

def two_sum():
    global count

    H = []
    for i in range(n):
        H.append(set())

    for x in data:
        insert(H, x)

    for t in range(-10000, 10000 + 1):
        for x in data:
            if t - x != x and lookup(H, t - x):
                count += 1

    print(count)

def insert(H, x):
    H[hashfunc(x)].add(x)

def lookup(H, x):
    if x in H[hashfunc(x)]:
        return True
    return False

def hashfunc(x):
    return (x >> 10) % n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    two_sum()
```

Above code is WAYY too slow.

EDIT: I've edited the code as per Willem Van Onsem's remark on using syntax like `[set()] * n` to initialise H, which is wrong. The code is still slow but I know more now lol.

Comment: But your `[set()]*n` does *not* create *n* different sets: it generates a list containing references to the same set.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem omg I just tested this, you're correct! I had no idea. Why is this happening? I usually initialise lists like [None]*n, so I naïvely thought [set()]*n would work too!

Comment: Can't you get rid of the lookup function? You only need if t -x in data. Then you don't need H either.

Comment: @Elan yeah I know, it's just formality actually, I'm studying hash tables. I do know that under the hood sets in python are just hash tables with dummy values. Actually initially I did just use `data` itself as my hash table. But that implementation and this one are both equally slow.